# how to view a particular user data from database?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, repeater

when user register the data,The data has been inserted into the database but a single user is going to login in the form while login the enter data in the database has been viewed in the user details page.but i need only a particular data of the user. and check my code in case of error so please mention me.

Below Attached database screenshot

in this screen shot two user saved information from the database (`ID 1` And `ID 10003`). if `ID=1` user login the details of the particular user need to be viewed but in this case if any one of the user login the whole database users details has been displayed. how to rectify the problem.

[DataBase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8b3V.png)

[Error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPtLy.png)

```
<div class="tg-bordertop tg-haslayout">
                    <div class="tg-formsection tg-experience">
                        <div class="tg-heading-border tg-small">
                            <h3>Doctor Social Network</h3>
                        </div>
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnsocial" runat="server" />
                         <div class="tg-education-detail tg-haslayout">
                        <asp:Repeater ID="rptsocial" runat="server">
                               <HeaderTemplate>
                                   <div class="table-responsive"> 
                              <table class="table-striped educations_wrap table" id="table-striped">
                                <thead class="cf">
                                  <tr>
                                    <th>Facebook</th>
                                    <th>Twitter</th>
                                    <th>linkedin</th>
                                    <th>Pinterest</th>
                                     <th>GooglePlusID</th>
                                  </tr>
                                </thead>
                                      </HeaderTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                   <tbody class="educations_item">
                                      <tr>
                                        <td data-title="FaceBook"><asp:Label ID="lblFaceBookID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FaceBookID") %>' />                       
                                             <div class="tg-table-hover education-action"> 
                                                <a id='<%#Eval("DoctorSocialID")%>' href="javascript:;" class="delete-me" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Socialdelete<%#Eval("DoctorSocialID")%>"><i class="tg-delete fa fa-close"></i></a>
                                                <a id='<%#Eval("DoctorSocialID")%>' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Socialedit<%#Eval("DoctorSocialID")%>" href="javascript:;" class="edit-me EditSocial"><i class="tg-edit fa fa-pencil"></i></a> 
                                             </div>
                                            <td data-title="Twitter"><asp:Label ID="lbiTwitterID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TwitterID") %>' /></td>
                                            <td data-title="linkedin"><asp:Label ID="lbllinkedinID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("linkedinID") %>' /></td>
                                             <td data-title="Pinterest"><asp:Label ID="lblPinterestID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PinterestID") %>' /></td>
                                           <td data-title="GooglePlus"><asp:Label ID="lblGooglePlusID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("GooglePlusID") %>' /></td>
                                        </td>
                                      </tr>
                                       <tr>
                                           <td>
                                                <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" id='Socialedit<%#Eval("DoctorSocialID")%>' tabindex="-1"
                                                role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="background-color:black;">
                                                <div class="modal-header" style="background-color:white;">
                                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                                                        ×</button> 
                                                    <h4 id="myModalLabel">
                                                       Edit Social Network</h4>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="modal-body" style="background-color:white;">
                                                <div class="errorEditTitle">
                                                    </div>
                                                    <table class="index-table">
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td>
                                                                <label>
                                                                    FaceBook<sub>*</sub></label>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td>
                                                               <asp:TextBox ID="txtFaceBookID" runat="server" onchange="javascript:EditSocialvalue(this);" Text='<%#Eval("FaceBookID")%>' required  class="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td>
                                                                <label>
                                                                    Twitter<sub>*</sub></label>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td>
                                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtTwitterID" runat="server" Class="form-control" onchange="javascript:EditSocialvalue1(this);" required Text='<%#Eval("TwitterID")%>' ></asp:TextBox>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td>
                                                                <label>
                                                                    linkedin<sub>*</sub></label>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td>
                                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtlinkedinID" runat="server" Class="form-control" Text='<%#Eval("linkedinID")%>' onchange="javascript:EditSocialvalue2(this);" ></asp:TextBox>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                         <tr>
                                                            <td>
                                                                <label>
                                                                    Pinterest<sub>*</sub></label>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td>
                                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPinterestID" runat="server" Class="form-control" Text='<%#Eval("PinterestID")%>' onchange="javascript:EditSocialvalue3(this);"></asp:TextBox>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                         <tr>
                                                            <td>
                                                                <label>
                                                                    GooglePlus<sub>*</sub></label>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td>
                                                                 <asp:TextBox ID="txtGooglePlusID" runat="server" Class="form-control" Text='<%#Eval("GooglePlusID")%>' onchange="javascript:EditSocialvalue4(this);"></asp:TextBox>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        </table>
                                                        </div>
                                                    <div class="modal-footer" style="background-color:white;">
                                                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="btnEditSocial"
                                                        value="Update" name="<%#Eval("DoctorSocialID")%>" />
                                                    <button class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                                                        Cancel</button>
                                                </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                <!----------------------------------------------------
                                 * Delete HTML Tempaltes
                                 ------------------------------------------------- -->
                                <!-- Modal -->
                                <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" id='Socialdelete<%#Eval("DoctorSocialID")%>' role="dialog">
                                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
                                        <div class="modal-content" style="width:350px">
                                            <div class="modal-header">
                                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                                <h4 class="modal-title">Delete Confirmation</h4>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="modal-body">
                                                <p>Are you sure you want to delete this record?<br /></p>
                                            </div><br />
                                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                            <button class="btn button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                                                Cancel</button>
                                                 <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="btnDeleteSocial"
                                                        value="Delete" name="<%#Eval("DoctorSocialID")%>" />
                                        </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                               </td>
                                           </tr>

                                     </tbody>
                                   </ItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                   </table>
                                    </div>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                               </asp:Repeater>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <div class="tg-addfield add-new-experiences">
                                <button type="button" id="AddSocialNetwork">
                                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                                    <span>Add Social Network</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>



                <!--Start Social -->
                 <div class="tg-bordertop tg-haslayout" id="ShowSocialNetwork" style="display:none;">
        <div class="tg-formsection tg-education">
            <div class="tg-heading-border tg-small">
                <h3>Add Social Network</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="tg-education-detail tg-haslayout">
              <table class="table-striped educations_wrap" id="table1">
                <thead class="cf">
                  <tr>
                    <th>Facebook</th>
                    <th>Twitter</th>
                    <th>linkedin</th>
                    <th>Pinterest</th>
                      <th>GooglePlusID</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                   <tbody class="educations_item">
                      <tr>
                       <td class="education-data edit-me-row" colspan="5">
                         <div class="education-data-wrap">
                            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFaceBookID" runat="server" Class="form-control" placeholder="FaceBook ID"></asp:TextBox>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtTwitterID" runat="server" Class="form-control" placeholder="Twitter ID"></asp:TextBox>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtlinkedinID" runat="server" Class="form-control" placeholder="linkedinID"></asp:TextBox>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPinterestID" runat="server" Class="form-control" placeholder="Pinterest"></asp:TextBox>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                              <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtGooglePlusID" runat="server" Class="form-control" placeholder="GooglePlus"></asp:TextBox>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                             <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                 <input type="button" id="btnSocial" class="btn btn-success" value="Save Social" />
                                </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                       </td>
                      </tr>
                     </tbody>
                   </table>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
                <!--End Socail -->
```

Save database function code:

```
function SaveDocSocial(response) {
            if (response == null) {
                callAjax({
                    url: pageUrl + '/SaveDocSocial',
                    data: '{"Doctorid": "' + $("#<%=hdnDoctorId.ClientID %>").val() + '","DoctorSocialID" : "' + $("#<%=hdnsocial.ClientID %>").val() + '","FaceBookID" : "' + $("#<%=txtFaceBookID.ClientID %>").val() + '","TwitterID" : "' + $("#<%=txtTwitterID.ClientID %>").val() + '","linkedinID" : "' + $("#<%=txtlinkedinID.ClientID %>").val() + '","PinterestID" : "' + $("#<%=txtPinterestID.ClientID %>").val() + '","GooglePlusID" : "' + $("#<%=txtGooglePlusID.ClientID %>").val() + '"}',
                    action: "SaveDocSocial"
                });
                window.location.reload();
            }
            else {
                loading(false);
                if (response.AjxContactId != null) {
                    $('#<%=hdnsocial.ClientID%>').val(response.AjxContactId);
                }
                msg(true, response.Message);
            }
        }
```

And Page load

```
this.BindSocial();
if (iDoctorID > 0)

            {hdnsocial.Value = iDoctorID.ToString();
}
```

Save Code

```
[WebMethod]
    public static UserAjax SaveDocSocial(string Doctorid, string DoctorSocialID, string FaceBookID, string TwitterID, string linkedinID, string PinterestID, string GooglePlusID)
    {
        UserAjax oUserAjax = new UserAjax();
        string CDoctorID = string.Empty;
        string DSocialID = string.Empty;
        int iDoctorID = 0;
        int iDoctorSocialID = 0;
        CDoctorID = Doctorid == null ? "" : Doctorid;
        if (Validation.IsShort(CDoctorID))
            iDoctorID = Convert.ToInt32(CDoctorID);
        DSocialID = DoctorSocialID == null ? "" : DoctorSocialID;
        if (Validation.IsShort(DSocialID))
            iDoctorSocialID = Convert.ToInt32(DSocialID);
        string sMessage = string.Empty;
        string sBuild = string.Empty;
        if (sMessage != "")
        {
            oUserAjax.Message = sMessage;
        }
        else
        {
            BD_Doctor iDoctor = new BD_Doctor();
            iDoctor.DoctorID = iDoctorID;
            iDoctor.DoctorSocialID = iDoctorSocialID;
            iDoctor.FaceBookID = FaceBookID;
            iDoctor.TwitterID = TwitterID;
            iDoctor.linkedinID = linkedinID;
            iDoctor.PinterestID = PinterestID;
            iDoctor.GooglePlusID = GooglePlusID;
            iDoctor.SaveSocial();
            //iDoctor.IsDefault = true;
            if (iDoctorID > 0)
            {
                sMessage = "Clinic Information successfully saved!";
                oUserAjax.AjxContactId = iDoctorID.ToString();
                oUserAjax.Message = sMessage;
            }
            else
            {
                sMessage = "Your submission failed!";
                oUserAjax.Message = sMessage;
            }
        }

        return oUserAjax;
    }
```

View Repeater Code :

```
private void BindSocial()
    {
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Doctorsocialnetwork", con))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    rptsocial.DataSource = dt;
                    rptsocial.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: if you only want to display one user, why use a repeater? Secondly, to get a single user, your SQL needs a "WHERE" clause.

Comment: can u help me sir please am a new member in this technology @ADyson

Comment: well, which bit of what I just said don't you understand? You are new to ASP.NET, or to SQL? Or both?

Comment: @ADyson  Both sir little i know..yes am a new in this technology

Comment: well there is too much to cover in an answer here if you don't understand anything about it (you perhaps need to study the basics a bit more before diving into existing code like this). But the things you need to understand are: 1) When the user is added, instead of simply reloading the current page, which is a list of all users, you need to make your code redirect to a page for that specific user (e.g. something like `window.location.href = http://www.example.com/user.aspx?ID=1` instead of `window.location.reload()`

Comment: That new page would make a query to the database based on the ID passed in, e.g. `SELECT * FROM DoctorSocialNetwork WHERE UserID = 1` (but obviously you would define the ID as a SQL parameter in reality). Then it would use a DetailsView or similar control to display the details of the specific user. You can read detailed tutorials online which explain all the principles and general code patterns you can use to implement this feature.

Comment: how to pass  'userID = 1' from BindSocial() page?@ADyson

Comment: in my example it's passed via the URL, as I just showed. Like I said, you are trying to run before you can walk. Study the basics, then this kind of task will become much simpler for you.

Comment: ok sir i will do thanks @ADyson

Answer (score 0):

Yes i done this solution

```
this.BindSocial(hdnsocial.Value);
```

Used where condition

```
#region Bind Social

    private void BindSocial(string hdnsocial)
    {
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
        BD_Doctor iDoctor = new BD_Doctor();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Doctorsocialnetwork where DoctorID = '" + hdnsocial + "'", con))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    rptsocial.DataSource = dt;
                    rptsocial.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion
```